# Moving items around in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been playing around with `ArrayList`s. What I'm trying to achieve is a method to do something like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

I'm trying to be able to move items up in the list, unless it is already at the top in which case it will stay the same. For example, if item 3 was moved the list would be:

```
Item 1
Item 3
Item 2
Item 4
```

From my small understanding at the moment then I would want something along the lines of:

```
IF arrayname index is not equal to 0
THEN move up
ELSE do nothing
```

The part I'm struggling with is the "move up" part. Any tips or code samples of how this could be achieved are much appreciated.

Comment: This question is worded confusingly. Are you trying to do a "bubble sort" that repeatedly uses a simple swap of 2 indices?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I came across this old question in my search for an answer, and I thought I would just post the solution I found in case someone else passes by here looking for the same.

For swapping 2 elements, Collections.swap is fine. But if we want to move more elements, there is a better solution that involves a creative use of Collections.sublist and Collections.rotate that I hadn't thought of until I saw it described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29

Here's a quote, but go there and read the whole thing for yourself too:

> Note that this method can usefully be applied to sublists to move one
>   or more elements within a list while preserving the order of the
>   remaining elements. For example, the following idiom moves the element
>   at index j forward to position k (which must be greater than or equal
>   to j):
>
> `Collections.rotate(list.subList(j, k+1), -1);`

Comment: In my application this sublist rotation appeared to be slower than the remove/insert-approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4938696/1025391

Comment: `greater than or equal (>=)`? what about `<=`?

Comment: @moooeeeep it took me some time to understand what the int in rotate(list, int) does.
It behaves as a carrousel, where the last index goes 1st, and the previously -2nd to last index- is now last (when positive ints are used); while on negative the direction changes.
This MAY be the reason why is slower because it's swapping each index one by one(?). judging by this quest. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50212335/11214643) it seems it's speed can be improved, but maybe not for the reason I'm pointing here.
But on the link, op mentions "Block-Swap Algorithm" would be faster, which gives a hint.

Answer (score 78):

A simple swap is far better for "moving something up" in an ArrayList:

```
if(i > 0) {
    Item toMove = arrayList.get(i);
    arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i-1));
    arrayList.set(i-1, toMove);
}
```

Because an ArrayList uses an array, if you remove an item from an ArrayList, it has to "shift" all the elements after that item upward to fill in the gap in the array. If you insert an item, it has to shift all the elements after that item to make room to insert it. These shifts can get very expensive if your array is very big. Since you know that you want to end up with the same number of elements in the list, doing a swap like this allows you to "move" an element to another location in the list very efficiently.

As Chris Buckler and Michal Kreuzman point out, there is even a handy method in the Collections class to reduce these three lines of code to one:

```
Collections.swap(arrayList, i, i-1);
```

Comment: This is great, collections.swap seems to be perfect. One slight problem ive noticed is that using this one something at the top of the list causes an out of bounds exception - it still works just how I wanted but is there any way to stop it throwing an out of bounds exception?

Comment: @user319940 Hi StriplingWarrior showed it in first code sample. Index i have to be greater than 0 `if(i > 0)`

Comment: heh, silly me, was trying it with while instead of if - thanks once again everyone. Hopefully this post will also help others in the future.

Comment: This only works if you're moving something up just a single index value. If you have to move something up or down by more than one index value, a swap is no longer useful and things get a little trickier.

Comment: @Javid Jamae: It's true that it's not as simple if you need to move the element more than one space. However, it's still far more efficient than removing and re-adding the element. If you're doing much moving-around of items, I'd definitely recommend a LinkedList.

Comment: Collections.swap(arrayList, i, i-1); This worked great..Thank you

Comment: Collections.swap(arrayList, oldposition, newposition); This worked great..Thank you

Answer (score 33):

To move up, remove and then add.

To remove - [ArrayList.remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) and assign the returned object to a variable
Then add this object back at the required index  -`ArrayList.add(int index, E element)`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

Comment: This is the only solution that actually works to change the order of items in the ArrayList.  Thanks!

Comment: Very elegant indeed!

Comment: with removing it's not moving, it's changing the positions of two objects (swap), moving - it's moving one object between some other two objects

Answer (score 32):

you can try this simple code, Collections.swap(list, i, j) is what you looking for.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");

    String toMoveUp = "3";
    while (list.indexOf(toMoveUp) != 0) {
        int i = list.indexOf(toMoveUp);
        Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 17):

As Mikkel posted before Collections.rotate is a simple way. I'm using this method for moving items up- and downward in a List.

```
public static <T> void moveItem(int sourceIndex, int targetIndex, List<T> list) {
    if (sourceIndex <= targetIndex) {
        Collections.rotate(list.subList(sourceIndex, targetIndex + 1), -1);
    } else {
        Collections.rotate(list.subList(targetIndex, sourceIndex + 1), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To `Move` item in list simply add:

```
// move item to index 0
Object object = ObjectList.get(index);
ObjectList.remove(index);
ObjectList.add(0,object);
```

To `Swap` two items in list simply add:

```
// swap item 10 with 20
Collections.swap(ObjectList,10,20);
```

Comment: ObjectList.remove(index) returns the object removed, so you can get rid of the line before. Just make it Object object = Objectlist.remove(index);

Answer (score 6):

Applying recursion to reorder items in an arraylist

```
public class ArrayListUtils {
            public static <T> void reArrange(List<T> list,int from, int to){
                if(from != to){
                     if(from > to)
                        reArrange(list,from -1, to);
                      else
                        reArrange(list,from +1, to);

                     Collections.swap(list, from, to);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving element with respect to each other is something I needed a lot in a project of mine. So I wrote a small util class that moves an element in an list to a position relative to another element. Feel free to use (and improve upon ;))

```
import java.util.List;

public class ListMoveUtil
{
    enum Position
    {
        BEFORE, AFTER
    };

    /**
     * Moves element `elementToMove` to be just before or just after `targetElement`.
     *
     * @param list
     * @param elementToMove
     * @param targetElement
     * @param pos
     */
    public static <T> void moveElementTo( List<T> list, T elementToMove, T targetElement, Position pos )
    {
        if ( elementToMove.equals( targetElement ) )
        {
            return;
        }
        int srcIndex = list.indexOf( elementToMove );
        int targetIndex = list.indexOf( targetElement );
        if ( srcIndex < 0 )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Element: " + elementToMove + " not in the list!" );
        }
        if ( targetIndex < 0 )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Element: " + targetElement + " not in the list!" );
        }
        list.remove( elementToMove );

        // if the element to move is after the targetelement in the list, just remove it
        // else the element to move is before the targetelement. When we removed it, the targetindex should be decreased by one
        if ( srcIndex < targetIndex )
        {
            targetIndex -= 1;
        }
        switch ( pos )
        {
            case AFTER:
                list.add( targetIndex + 1, elementToMove );
                break;
            case BEFORE:
                list.add( targetIndex, elementToMove );
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from `toIndex` and shift nearby elements until it reaches `fromIndex`. Finally set element at `fromIndex` to `toIndex`.

```
fun <E> ArrayList<E>.move(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) {
    if (fromIndex >= size || fromIndex < 0) {
        throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(fromIndex, size))
    }
    if (toIndex >= size || toIndex < 0) {
        throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(toIndex, size))
    }
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) return
    var index = toIndex
    var item = get(index)
    if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
        while (index < fromIndex) {
            index++
            item = set(index, item)
        }
    } else {
        while (index > fromIndex) {
            index--
            item = set(index, item)
        }
    }
    set(toIndex, item)
}

private fun outOfBoundsMsg(index: Int, size: Int): String {
    return "Index: $index, Size: $size"
}
```