# Iterator removal/edit is safe, however I also need to edit all following Iterations

Tags: java, optimization, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have read a little about `ConcurrentModificationException` in stackflow and my actual update appears not to be the issue, it could be a problem in my design or I need a technique I haven't learnt yet.

Example Situation:
My iterator is running along position markers.
Then an action can be performed to shift the markers over (e.g. Inserting into string).
All Markers greater than the current position must also be shifted to preserve correctness.

Task:
How do I update the remaining markers without the iterator exploding?
Can I refresh the iterator, or break and start the loop again?

The following code is abstracted from my work.

```
 public void innerLoop(Boolean b) {
    //An Example of what I'm working with
    HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>() {
        {
            put("Nonce",
                new HashSet<Integer>() {

                {
                    add(1);
                    add(2);
                    add(3);
                    add(4);
                    add(5);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //for each key
    for (String key: map.keySet()) {
        HashSet<Integer> positions = map.get(key);

        //for each integer
        for (Iterator<Integer> it = positions.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Integer position = it.next();

            System.out.println("position =" + position);
            //(out of scope) decision requiring elements from the outter loops
            if (new Random().nextBoolean()&&b) {
                //shift position by +4 (or whatever)
                //and every other (int >= position)
                System.out.println("Shift " + position + " by 4");
                Integer shift = 4;
                update(position,
                       shift,
                       positions);
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void update(Integer current,
                   Integer diff,
                   Set<Integer> set) {

    if (set != null) {
        HashSet<Integer> temp = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (Integer old: set) {
            if (old >= current) {
                temp.add(old);
                System.out.println(old + "Added to temp");
            }
        }

        for (Integer old: temp) {
            set.remove(old);
            System.out.println(old + "removed");
            set.add(old + diff);
            System.out.println((old + diff) + "Added");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edited with Garrett Hall Solution**

```
 public void nestedloops() {

    HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>() {
        {
            put("Hello",
                new HashSet<Integer>() {

                {
                    add(5);
                    add(2);
                    add(3);
                    add(4);
                    add(1);
                    add(6);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //for each key
    for (String key: map.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.get(key));
        //for each integer
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
            Integer position = positions.get(i);
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] =" + position);
            //out of scope decision
            if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
                //shift position by +4
                //and every other (int >= position)
                System.out.println("Shift after " + position + " by 4");
                Integer shift = 4;
                //Update the array
                for (int j = 0; j < positions.size(); j++) {
                    Integer checkPosition = positions.get(j);
                    if (checkPosition > position) {
                        System.out.println(checkPosition + "increased by 4");
                        positions.set(j,
                                      checkPosition + shift);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Add updated Array
        map.put(key,
                new HashSet<Integer>(positions));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best bet is indexing the `HashSet` by putting it into a list.  Then you can use indices to refer to elements rather than an `Iterator`.  So long as you are not removing or adding (only updating) elements, then your indices will be correct.  Otherwise you will have to account for that.  Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.get(key));
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i ++) {
  // updating list
  for (int j = i; i < positions.size(); j ++) {
    positions.set(j, positions.get(i) + diff);
  }
}
```

Comment: map.keyset() returns Set<String>
I would need 
`for(String key: map.keyset() ){
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.get(key));`

So I move along the array of ints but I can change the values as long as I don't change the size of the array?

Initially that looks like what I want, let me check

Comment: The `ArrayList` should be instantiated the same way `positions` is in your current code.  (Update with `map.get(key)` to reflect that).

Comment: @GarrettHall I have added you solution to my question.

Comment: @GarrettHall is the put I placed at the end required to retain the changes made?

Comment: Correct, ultimately you need to modify `map` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the original set to a list so that you don't need to worry about the current iteration code. Then update a secondary list (not being iterated).

Reasons:

1. You can't iterate and modify your original collection at once (there is no way around the `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`)
2. Nice [one liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938626/moving-items-around-in-an-arraylist) to shift items in a list.

   ```
   Collections.rotate(list.subList(j, k+1), -1);
   ```
3. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) will be able to handle the "find first index that satisfies that predicate and transform the list" which a bunch of utility methods.

Comment: Q: If I have "editPositions" and "loopingPositions".
In loopingPositions I find I want to shift `position = 3`.
I update `editPositions = {1, 2, 3+4, 4+4, 5+4} = {1,2,7,8,9}`
the next iteration of loopingPositions will be `position = 4`, which is out-dated when I really needed `position = 8`. Is that what would happen?

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from swapping the original list for it's copy at each Iteration, them produce a new copy, rotate it, swap with the previous copy and so on (it is expensive but will work). Views can also mitigate performance problems.

Comment: A better strategy would involve a cumulative counter of "rotated positions" (that starts with `0`), then you always consider `loopingPosition + cumulativeCounter` as the position to shift `editPositions`, and, at the end of each iteration, make `cumulativeCounter += diff` this way you can iterate over the original values and still get the desired result using only a single copy of the original collection.

Comment: I've added your edit to the question as best I can understand. It appears to work correctly but how do I retain on exit the appropriate amount of shift to per position. `{1+(4*0), 2+(4*1), 3+(4*2), 4+(4*2), 5(4*3)}` = `{1,6,11,12,17}`

Comment: Just create a temp `List` and add `positionValue + counterShift` (after `counterShift` has been updated)  at each iteration... Or use `Guava` [transform](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Functions) functions to do it in one step ;)