# select element inside an arraylist and swap to the next element and previous element

Tags: java, arraylist, swap

My doubt is how to select an element in an ArrayList so that I can swap with the next element in the case I want to move the element down and swap to the previous element in the case, move the item up.

```
public class ShapesFX{

        private ArrayList <Shape> shapes;

        public ShapesFX() {
            this.shapes= new ArrayList <> ();
    }

  / **
     * Swap positions with the immediate previous element. The method can not
     * Be successful if the reference element is the last.
     *
     * @ Param element element reference to the exchange
     * @ Return true if the exchange was successful. false, d.c.
     * @ Throws Exception if the element does not exist
     * /

    @ Override
    public boolean moveUP (Shape element) throws Exception {
        if (element != null) {
            throw new Exception ("Element does not exist");
        } else if (element != Null) {
            for (FormaGeometrica sh : this.shapes) {
                if (sh == element) {
                    Collections.swap ((List<Shape>) element, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

  / **
     * Swap positions with the next immediate element. The method can not
     * Be successful if the reference element is the first.
     *
     * @ Param element element reference to the exchange
     * @ Return true if the exchange was successful. false, d.c.
     * @ Throws Exception if the element does not exist
     * /

    @ Override 
    public boolean moverDown (Shape element) throws Exception {
        if (element != null) {
            throw new Exception ("Element does not exist");
        } else if (element != Null) {
            for (Shape sh : this.shapes) {
                if (sh == element) {
                    Collections.swap ((List<Shape>) element, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and if this methods is correctly, one example of the output is

```
--- List of Figures ---
F1
F2
F3
F4

--- Move F2 UP ---
F2
F1
F3
F4

F2 change position with F1

--- Move F3 DOWN ---
F2
F1
F4
F3

F3 change position with F4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938626/moving-items-around-in-an-arraylist)

Comment: Select the index of element which you want to move and swap with the previous index element or element in the next index

Comment: Can you make sure that the code you posted compiles with a java compiler? Example: `Else` -> `else`, `! =` -> `!=`, `/ **` -> `/**` etc.

Comment: I think you need to (re)read the Javadoc for Collections.swap.  You are casting a Shape to a List, and you are specifying the same value for both of the index parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Bolwidt, Its my fault, but I re-edit the code now

Comment: Andrew this topics(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938626/moving-items-around-in-an-arraylist) is good but I wanna move just 2 element and they say me to use Collections.Swap(item,0,1);

Comment: Vwin, you are the one who is right, maybe I need to Select the index of element which you want to move and swap with the previous index element or element in the next index, I will try