# how to use a for loop to move an element in an arraylist in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I need help coding the following:

In your NotebookTest driver program, use a For loop to move a note up for a specified number of moves (which you will store in a
variable). Set the value of this variable to 2 and test your For loop. Use the method you created in step D.

Make a corresponding For loop to move a note down a specified number of times.

Code for Notebook Class:

```
public class Notebook {

    private ArrayList < String > notes;

    public Notebook() {
        this.notes = new ArrayList < String > ();
    }

    public ArrayList < String > getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    //adds a note to list and won't allow duplicate
    public void addNote(String note) {
        if (!notes.contains(note)) {
            notes.add(note);
        }
    }

    //this was the original addNote Method
    /*public void addNote(String note) {
        this.notes.add(note);
    }*/

    //removes a note
    public void deleteNote(String note) {
        this.notes.remove(note);
    }

    //returns the size of list
    public int numberOfNotes() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    // gets the position of a note based on its value
    public int getNoteNumber(String note) {
        return notes.indexOf(note);
    }

    //returns text in a position
    public String getNote(int note) {
        return notes.get(note);
    }

    //updates text of a given position 
    public void setNote(int note, String nt) {
        notes.set(note, nt);
    }

    //moves note up one in list
    public void moveNoteUp(String note) {
        Collections.swap(notes, notes.indexOf(note), notes.indexOf(note) - 1);
    }

    //moves note down one in list
    public void moveNoteDown(String note) {
        Collections.swap(notes, notes.indexOf(note), notes.indexOf(note) + 1);
    }

}
```

Code for NotebookTest

```
public class NotebookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Notebook ntb = new Notebook();
        System.out.println("Notebook has  " + ntb.numberOfNotes());
        ntb.addNote("joe");
        ntb.addNote("ryan");
        ntb.addNote("bill");
        ntb.addNote("jill");
        ntb.addNote("beth");
        System.out.println("Notebook has  " + ntb.numberOfNotes());
        ntb.deleteNote("ryan");
        System.out.println("Notebook has  " + ntb.numberOfNotes());
        System.out.println("Bill is at position " + ntb.getNoteNumber("bill") + " in the Arraylist");
        System.out.println(ntb.getNote(0) + " is in position 0 of the Arraylist");
        ntb.setNote(0, "phil");
        System.out.println("I changed the text of position 0 to " + ntb.getNote(0));
        ntb.addNote("bill");
        System.out.println("Notebook has  " + ntb.numberOfNotes());
        ntb.addNote("jeff");
        System.out.println("Notebook has  " + ntb.numberOfNotes());
        System.out.println(ntb.getNotes());
        ntb.moveNoteUp("jeff");
        System.out.println(ntb.getNotes());
        ntb.moveNoteDown("jill");
        System.out.println(ntb.getNotes());

    }

}
```

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938626/moving-items-around-in-an-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

So you need to write the code to do this or test this? If it's do this try:

```
public void moveNoteUpBy(String note, int x){
      for(int n=0; n<x; n++){
          moveNoteUp(...);
      }
}
```

Same for move note down