# Java Collections.rotate() implementation algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

It uses Juggling Algorithm for small lists and Reversal Algorithm for large or linked lists. Why not Block-Swap Algorithm for small or RandomAccess lists? It's performance is better in experimental runs for vectors.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8 states that the `rotate()` method has been around since 1.4 and that the `Collections` class is authored by Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter. I would recommend digging through 1.4 mailing lists to find motivation for the current implementation.

Comment: thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell you why the Java developers have not done this:

- Maybe they are not aware of the performance result you are talking about
- Maybe they are aware but don't think the performance difference would be significant (across all Java use-cases)
- Maybe they have tried your idea and it doesn't have a significant benefit
- Maybe they are aware of the issue, but have given other issue higher priority.

Remember that the Java team is (largely) employed by Oracle, and Oracle management sets the agenda and the priorities for Java's evolution.

---

If you just asked this question out of curiosity, we can end here.

If you asked this because you think that "something should be done", then I suggest the following:

1. Develop a decent micro-benchmark to test the performance of `rotate()` for a variety of collection types, a variety of collection sizes.  (Use JMH ...)
2. Code modifications to the relevant classes to implement `rotate()` in the "better" way.
3. Benchmark your version and the existing version and compare the results.
4. If the difference is significant, submit a patch for the latest version of OpenJDK that implements your modifications.  Include your benchmarks and your results as supporting evidence.

This won't necessarily achieve the result that you want, but it is more likely to succeed than submitting an RFE and relying on the OpenJDK team to do all of the legwork.

Comment: I expected  "We cannot tell you why" reply, of course.

Comment: Results of experimental runs are present in Jon Bentley' "Programming Pearls", directly in the section that Collections.rotate() method reference suggests to look for details.

Comment: The results are noted. But you are telling the wrong people.   Please see my "if you think something should be done ....".